# Is there is any display announcement message to user know new version update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm developing chrome extension, as I know Chrome Developer Dashboard automatic updated new versions to users when there is has new version in chrome store. But I want to announcement to user know that have new version extension before user accept update?

Answer (score 2):

There is an event that allows you to intercept "update available" state as long as your extension is running:

> [**`onUpdateAvailable`**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onUpdateAvailable)
>
> Fired when an update is available, but isn't installed immediately because the app is currently running.

However, **you cannot allow the user to cancel an update**. It will be installed as the latest next time Chrome is restarted:

> If you do nothing, the update will be installed the next time the background page gets unloaded, if you want it to be installed sooner you can explicitly call `chrome.runtime.reload()`. If your extension is using a persistent background page, the background page of course never gets unloaded, so unless you call `chrome.runtime.reload()` manually in response to this event the update will not get installed until the next time chrome itself restarts.

The purpose of this event is to allow your extension to gracefully end operations before it is updated. If you don't listen to this event:

> If no handlers are listening for this event, and your extension has a persistent background page, it behaves as if `chrome.runtime.reload()` is called in response to this event.

---

### So, to recap:

There is no way for you to stop an update on the client, but you can delay an update.

```
chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable.addListener( function(details) {
  // Show a dialog to the user that an update to version `details.version`
  // is available, and ask if they want to update now

  if (updateNow) {
    // Gracefully terminate all work
    chrome.runtime.reload();
  }
});
```

---

And to detect *after an update* that it happened (and maybe present a changelog to the user, etc.),
you can listen to the `onInstalled` event:

> [onInstalled](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled)
>
> Fired when the extension is first installed, when the extension is updated to a new version, and when Chrome is updated to a new version.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener( function(details) {
  switch(details.reason) {
    case "install":
      // First installation
      break;
    case "update":
      // First run after an update
      break;
  }
});
```